# Compilers disagree on accepting this view::keys code

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Out of 3 compilers only gcc accepts this code. I guess clang problem is that it uses antique libstdc++, but MSVC and GCC should support ranges code.

What is the standard mandated behavior?

```
#include<array>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include<ranges>

constexpr std::array<std::pair<int, double>,2> arr{std::pair{1,1.1},std::pair{2,2.2}};

int main(){
    auto it = std::ranges::find(arr | std::views::keys , 2);    
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hnnb38cPM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs [P2017R1](https://wg21.link/P2017R1) (conditionally borrowed ranges) to work; without that, `arr | std::views::keys` is not a `borrowed_range`, and so `ranges::find` returns `dangling`.

Presumably the MSVC version on godbolt doesn't have that paper implemented.

Comment: Ah it is C++23 thing, so that is why it is still not implemented... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support